# Using a method in an object will not give me values

Tags: javascript, methods

I am trying to make a simple exercise, non realistic, that calculates the tax out of bills and stores them in arrays allong with another array that includes total values.

I really dont know why this method wont work. Notably, i can make functions work outside of the object (and solve my problem), but no matter when i use methods in this instance or any other, they just wont work inside of objects. Normally, i would expect to have an array 'tax' and array 'finalValues'. Nothing gives me errors but wont run it either.

So i posted it here to figure out why because it really drives me crazy :D

ps: I am using mdn, w3school for resources but also udemy. I am using visual code studio to write anything (but also tried brackets for this one). I used mozilla and chrome to test it, also used code pen.

```js
var stavros = {
    fullName: 'Stavros Vas',
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    calcTips: function() {
        this.tax = [];
        this.finalValues = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            
            var percentage;
            var bill = this.bills[i];

            if (bill < 50) {
                percentage = 0.1;
            } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
                percentage = 0.15;
            } else {
                percentage = 0.2;
            }

            this.tax[i] = bill * percentage;
            this.finalValues[i] = bill + bill * percentage;
        }
    }
};

console.log(stavros);
```

Thanks!

Comment: In your example code, you're not using the `calcTips` method anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, just execute it `stavros.calcTips()`

```js
var stavros = {
    fullName: 'Stavros Vas',
    bills: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    calcTips: function() {
        this.tax = [];
        this.finalValues = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < this.bills.length; i++) {
            
            var bill = this.bills[i];

            if (bill < 50) {
                percentage = 0.1;
            } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200) {
                percentage = 0.15;
            } else {
                percentage = 0.2;
            }

            this.tax[i] = bill * percentage;
            this.finalValues[i] = bill + bill * percentage;
        }
    }
};
stavros.calcTips(); // added
console.log(stavros);
```

Comment: Well, what i can i say, at times like this i feel like i need to apologize for so silly mistakes. Thanks :D